# SUMIF function multiple references

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif, sumifs

How can i use the sumif function on multiple references.

```
GROUP   COLOUR  TOTAL
GROUP A BLUE    50
GROUP A BLUE    100
GROUP A GREEN   25
GROUP A YELLOW  50
GROUP A GREEN   35
GROUP B GREEN   45
GROUP B RED 30
GROUP B RED 5
GROUP B BLUE    7
GROUP A BLUE    65
GROUP A YELLOW  88
GROUP A GREEN   10
GROUP B BLUE    45
GROUP B RED 56
GROUP A RED 89
GROUP A YELLOW  100
GROUP A PURPLE  1
GROUP B PURPLE  30
GROUP B PURPLE  45
```

I want to count the total (From the total column) against each colour, however, also against the group.

I created a new table, which removes the duplicate colours & next to this i want to include the total of each colour against each group. So the results would look like....

```
COLOUR  Group A   Group B
BLUE    215        52
GREEN   70         45
YELLOW      
RED     
PURPLE
```

Hope that makes sense. Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Why not use a pivot table - tailor made for this?

Comment: `SUMIFS()`?  Under the "Group A" header in your output sheet, it'd be something like: `=SUMIFS([total range],[Group range],$A2,[color range],B$1)` and drag over/down I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula you're looking for is SUMIFS(), it's perfect for this case. I put Group in A1:A19, Colour in B1:B19, and Total in C1:C19

Answer table was laid out from A24:C29

=SUMIFS($C$1:$C$19,$B$1:$B$19,$A25,$A$1:$A$19,B$24)

The way this works, first it requests the Sum Range, that would be your Total Column. Next it will want the first criteria range, I put in colour. It will then request the first criteria. I selected the first colour. The same process is completed for each new criteria until they have all been included.

It's important with this formula that the criteria range be of the same size as the sum range. Otherwise you will get an error.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that applying SUMIFS() which looks at more than one condition. If we consider the first table is in the columns A to C and the summary table on the E to G the formula would look like that for cell F2 (Group A - BLUE):

```
+SUMIFS(C:C,$E2,B:B,F$1,A:A)
```

You can copy this formula to the range F2:G6 to have the full summary table fill.

Answer (score 0):

Try usings SUMIFS (notice the 'S') since it looks at multiple criteria. For example, if you wanted to sum up the values that are both Group A and also Blue:

```
SUMIFS(C:C, A:A, "=Group A", B:B, "=Blue")
```